# Interchange differential operator with Lebesgue integral.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, integration, lebesgue-integral

Under what condition am I able to interchange a differential operator with an integral? More precisely, given a function $f:\Omega\times U\to\Bbb R$ from a measure space $(\Omega,\mathscr A,\mu)$ and $U\subset\Bbb R^n$ with the property $f(\cdot,y)\in L^1(\mu)$ for all $y\in U$ and $f(x,\cdot)$ is in the domain of some differential operator $D$ for all $x\in\Omega$, when is it the case that:
$$
D\int_\Omega f(x,y)\,d\mu(x)=\int_\Omega Df(x,y)\,d\mu(x)
$$
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Theorems 4 and 5 in Roussas' "An Introduction to Measure-theoretic Probability" (chapter 5 p.97) give sufficient conditions for $n=1$.

Comment: I've downvoted because I feel that "answering" by referencing a book that might not be available to the OP isn't particularly helpful. A comment containing the reference would IMHO have been fine, though.

Comment: @fgp A reference is an answer. Getting downvoted and being received negatively after taking the effort and time to write a reference for a result I know where to find (and for which I do not wish to re-transcribe the theorems in the reference) just makes want to stop answering such questions in the future.

Comment: Library call number: QA273.R864 2005 for the book.